# Can I use C++11 lambda with libevent?

Tags: c++11, lambda, libevent, boost-lambda

There is a callback function type in libevent used by event_new().

```
typedef void (*event_callback_fn)(evutil_socket_t, short, void *);
```

I want use lambda with event_callback_fn.

If I use

```
[](evutil_socket_t fd, short flags, void * _param){}
```

everything is OK.
But if I use the lambda capture list

```
[&](evutil_socket_t fd, short flags, void * _param){}
```

event_new() will not be compiled.

Comment: Only a capture-less lambda may be  converted to a pointer to functions. If you need captures then you need to solve it some other way.

Comment: Short answer is no. You should understand what [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming))s and [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming))s are. However, you could pass the closure as the `void *` client data

Comment: @ Basile Starynkevitch, so  event_new(_base, -1, EV_TIMEOUT, [](evutil_socket_t fd, short flags, void * _param){
    }, [](){}); like this? still compile error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type alias

```
void (*event_callback_fn)(evutil_socket_t, short, void *);
```

is a function pointer. Lambdas can automatically convert to function pointers, when they don't capture anything. As soon as you define a closure (stateful lambda), you can't pass it as an argument of type `event_callback_fn`.